# How to save all email contents in magento?

Tags: magento, save

I want to keep track of all the mails send from my magento. I want to save all emails contents, not just templates.

Comment: In which place you have to save email content ?

Comment: i am creating marketplace like ebay. so i want to save all emails and show as inbox, sent items like that in everybody account

Answer (score 1):

There are two base(-ish) methods Magento uses to send emails: `Mage_Core_Model_Email::send` and `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template::send`. Both of those methods use `Zend_Mail::send` internally, which takes an optional `Zend_Mail_Transport_Abstract` argument. You would need to substitute the default transport for one of your own that both sends the email *and* stashes it somewhere (db, file or what-have-you) to achieve your stated goal.

Unfortunately, there do not seem to be any injection points in the two `Mage_Core…::send` methods I mentioned, so you may have to rewrite them in order to override them *just* to inject your own transport.

I wrote [a module to save emails to file](https://github.com/kojiromike/LogMail) *instead* of sending them, with the goal of using it solely for debugging on dev machines where sending real email was a hassle. But you may find it informative nonetheless.